# Client to consume a web service with NTLM authentication

Tags: web-services, soap

Getting this error while calling the service.

**401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credential**

I tried creating a **NtlmAuthenticator** class which extends **Authenticator**
and passing on the credentials with DOMAIN\USERNAME and PASSWORD format.
Also set Authenticator.setDefault(ntlmAuthenticator). Doesnt't works out.

Any response would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On following the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html) found out that NTLM can be used with proxies or servers, but not with both at the same time.

Used [apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) and this time it worked.

Added the below code

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);
//httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```